# Are the integer points of a simple linear algebraic group 2-generated?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Set Up:

Let $ K $ be a totally real number field. Let $ \mathcal{O}_K $ be the ring of integers of $ K $. Let $ G $ be a simple linear algebraic group. Suppose that $ G(\mathbb{R}) $ is a compact Lie group. $ G(\mathcal{O}_K) $ must be discrete since it is an arithmetic group and then $ G(\mathcal{O}_K) $ is a discrete subgroup of the compact group $ G(\mathbb{R}) $ so it must be finite.

Question:

What can we learn about the finite group $ G(\mathcal{O}_K) $? For example, using the assumption that $ G $ is simple, can we prove that $ G(\mathcal{O}_K) $ is 2-generated?

Motivation:

Finite simple groups are known to be 2-generated https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements
, maybe something similar carries over here?

Another slightly similar fact is that a compact simple Lie groups are topologically 2-generated and moreover the 2 generators can be chosen to have have finite order https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431456/semisimple-compact-lie-group-topologically-generated-by-two-finite-order-element?noredirect=1&lq=1